# Separate equation numbering in algorithm environment

Tags: equations, numbering, algorithms, algorithm2e

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%Algorithms:
\usepackage[boxruled]{algorithm2e} %Fancy algorithms
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

Blah blah blah

\begin{equation}
    E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{algorithm}[ht!] 
  \SetAlgoNoLine
  \SetAlgoNoEnd
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \caption{My method}
  \begin{minipage}[ht]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\algomargin\relax}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Solve this equation:
        \begin{equation}
            \nabla f = u \tag{Alg1.1}
        \end{equation}
    \item Then, solve this equation:
        \begin{equation}
            \nabla f + cf = u' \tag{Alg1.2}
        \end{equation}
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}
%
\end{algorithm}

blah blah blah

\begin{equation}
    E \ne mc^3
\end{equation}

\begin{algorithm}[ht!] 
  \SetAlgoNoLine
  \SetAlgoNoEnd
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \caption{My inverse method}
  \begin{minipage}[ht]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\algomargin\relax}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Update $u$:
        \begin{equation}
            u = \nabla f \tag{Alg2.1}
        \end{equation}
    \item Update $u'$:
        \begin{equation}
            u' = \nabla f + cf \tag{Alg2.2}
        \end{equation}
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}
\end{algorithm}

blah blah blah

\begin{equation}
    E \ne mc^4
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to automate the process of doing a different numbering system for equations inside the algorithm environment?

In particular, I would like all equations inside the Algorithms to be numbered as AlgX.Y where X is the algorithm number and Y is the equation number within Algorithm X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a method similar to `subequations`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%Algorithms:
\usepackage[boxruled]{algorithm2e} %Fancy algorithms
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{\algoequations}
\AtEndEnvironment{algorithm}{\restoreequations}
\newcounter{algosavedequation}
\newcommand{\algoequations}{%
  \setcounter{algosavedequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{Alg\thealgocf.\arabic{equation}}%
}
\newcommand{\restoreequations}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{algosavedequation}}%
}


\begin{document}

Blah blah blah

\begin{equation}
    E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{algorithm}[ht!] 
  \SetAlgoNoLine
  \SetAlgoNoEnd
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \caption{My method}
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\algomargin\relax}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Solve this equation:
        \begin{equation}
            \nabla f = u
        \end{equation}
    \item Then, solve this equation:
        \begin{equation}
            \nabla f + cf = u'
        \end{equation}
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}
%
\end{algorithm}

blah blah blah

\begin{equation}
    E \ne mc^3
\end{equation}

\begin{algorithm}[ht!] 
  \SetAlgoNoLine
  \SetAlgoNoEnd
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \caption{My inverse method}
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\algomargin\relax}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Update $u$:
        \begin{equation}
            u = \nabla f
        \end{equation}
    \item Update $u'$:
        \begin{equation}
            u' = \nabla f + cf
        \end{equation}
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}
\end{algorithm}

blah blah blah

\begin{equation}
    E \ne mc^4
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is no `ht` option for `minipage`.